# Why wont this assignment work?

Tags: java

I've got a class `Results` which `extends ArrayList<Results>`. I've got an object `i` which has a function `i.getResults()` which returns an `ArrayList` of type `ArrayList<Results>`. I'm attempting the following:

```
Results result = i.getResults();
```

However, I'm getting a type mismatch error. Why can't I make this assignment? How can I assign it to type Results?

**EDIT:** To explain what I'm trying to achieve.. I don't have access to the `ArrayList<Results>` code and I'd like to make it implement a certain class which I have `Results` implementing

Comment: It is important to have a clear idea of what you are trying to achieve. Can you describe in English what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: Ok, now imagine you are explaining this to someone non-technical.  BTW: `ArrayList<Results>` is just the code for `ArrayList` which everyone has access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - `ArrayList<Results>` isn't a `Results`. `Results` is an `ArrayList<Results>` though, you could assign the other way.

Comment: Well, I need to Implement something onto the type ArrayList<Results> but don't have the code to that class. How would I do this?

Comment: Make a wrapper class instead of extending.

Comment: One option is to give Results a constructor that takes an ArrayList<Results>

Comment: Result(Collection<? extends Results> results) { super(results); } would probably do the job.

Comment: @jeff Are you sure you meant it to extend results? throws back an undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I probably meant Result.  You just want a constructor to take a copy of the incoming array list and store it in your list.

Comment: Results(Collection<? extends Results> results){
  super(results);
 } gives back undefined

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a parent to the child class. This is not possible. You can assign do

```
ArrayList<Result> list = new Results();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the relationship the wrong way round.

```
class T {}
class S extends T {}
```

The [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that:

> in a computer program if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., objects of type S may be substitutes for objects of type T), without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task performed, etc.)

So in other words, anywhere that expects a `T` can get an `S` with no problems.  Something that wants an `S` cannot be given a `T` because it isn't specific enough.

In your example, `i.getResults()` returns an `ArrayList<Results>`.  You can't assign that to `Results` because `Results` is more specific than the array list.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
  Results extends ArrayList<Results>
```

So anywhere you might use ArrayList you can use Results, but not vice-versa. When you say
**extends** you are saying I can do everything he can do, and a little bit more.

```
  C extends D
```

says: if all you need is a D then you can use either a C or a D. But someone needing a C cannot accept a D, because it doesn have all the capabilities C offers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to assign an object of a superclass type to a reference of a subclass type, and of course that's a compile-time error, because it might not be valid. It's the same as if you tried to assign the return value of a method that returns `Object` to a variable of type `String`. If you are absolutely sure the `getResults()` method returns a `Results` object, you should change its return type. Or if you're only sure of it in this context, you can use a cast.